# Using logical fallacies in conjunction with data to make things sounds right

Tags: discussion

[Does sexual abuse lead to homosexuality?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/does-sexual-abuse-lead-to-homosexuality?rq=1)

I came across this answer today(top answer, the accepted one), and it's using data, proper references etc, and then uses logical fallacies, and improper deduction, and with that it gets the feel of being a proper answer.

This leads to an answer that SOUNDS correct, and for people not very good at logic, or if people just skim, this sounds like a great answer that explains everything, and is proper proof against something.
It's something very dangerous for credibility of site, and to get to right conclusions. Even IF you get to the right conclusion using fallacies, then it's like doing math, doing the calculations completely wrong, but still get right answer...

**How should usage of logical fallacies to make something sound right be treated?**

Answer (score 3):

A basic tenet of the Stack Exchange system is the idea that the community may be slow, but will eventually correct the mistake.

So, downvote the bad answer, add a comment explaining the objection clearly enough that others will also downvote and hopefully the answerer will understand their mistake and delete/correct, add a competing answer that doesn't suffer from the flaw, wait for the voting system to catch up so your answer appears first or second.

I think there would have to be exceptional circumstances for us conclude this system would be unsuccessful and should be overridden.

Comment: A problem with SE is that up voting is free, while down voting costs you. That means answers much easier get up voted than down voted, even if they contains improper answers. That is especially true when it comes to fallacies, which might look nice and sounds right.

Comment: So write a spectacular answer that overtakes it...

Comment: Fair enough, I guess that's how it is to be approached.